# 21.10 ova default username and password

Tags: system-installation

Deployed the 21.10 ova (`impish-server-cloudimg-amd64.ova`) on a ESXi host, and when powered up it goes straight to a login, but there I can't find a setup document that lists the default username and password.

Comment: You should find that information where you downloaded it from.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing on some posts that there is *no* default human user account built into these cloud images. You seem to be required to create a human user account using cloud-init or other tool.